# How to set the item for a CarouselView from code behind?

Tags: c#, android, ios, xamarin, xamarin.forms

I have a CarouselView which is bound to an ItemsSource of images.
But I want to change the current Image shown by changing the index of the CarouselView.

I have tried using CarouselView.Position to the index of the element that has to be selected. But unfortunately this does not work.

How can I achieve this?
Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I have tried using CarouselView.Position to the index of the element that has to be selected. But unfortunately this does not work.

Since you're using data binding for `ItemsSource` of `CarouselView`, you can implement the `INotifyPropertyChanged` interface for your image model.

For example:

```
<ContentPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
             xmlns:cv="clr-namespace:Xamarin.Forms;assembly=Xamarin.Forms.CarouselView"
             x:Class="FormsIssue2.Page1">
    <Grid>
        <cv:CarouselView ItemsSource="{Binding Zoos, Mode=OneWay}" x:Name="CarouselZoos">
            <cv:CarouselView.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <Grid>
                        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                            <RowDefinition Height="*" />
                            <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
                        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                        <Image Grid.RowSpan="2" Aspect="AspectFill" Source="{Binding ImageUrl, Mode=OneWay}" />
                        <StackLayout Grid.Row="1" BackgroundColor="#80000000" Padding="12">
                            <Label TextColor="White" Text="{Binding Name, Mode=OneWay}" FontSize="16" HorizontalOptions="Center" VerticalOptions="CenterAndExpand" />
                        </StackLayout>
                    </Grid>
                </DataTemplate>
            </cv:CarouselView.ItemTemplate>
        </cv:CarouselView>
    </Grid>
</ContentPage>
```

Code behind:

```
public partial class Page1 : ContentPage
{
    public Page1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        Zoos = new ObservableCollection<Zoo>
      {
        new Zoo
        {
            ImageUrl = "http://wallpaper-gallery.net/images/image/image-13.jpg",
            Name = "Woodland Park Zoo"
        },
            new Zoo
        {
            ImageUrl =  "https://s3-us-west-1.amazonaws.com/powr/defaults/image-slider2.jpg",
            Name = "Cleveland Zoo"
            },
        new Zoo
        {
            ImageUrl = "https://i.stack.imgur.com/WCveg.jpg",
            Name = "Phoenix Zoo"
        }
    };

        //CarouselZoos.ItemsSource = Zoos;
        this.BindingContext = this;
        CarouselZoos.ItemSelected += CarouselZoos_ItemSelected;
    }

    private void CarouselZoos_ItemSelected(object sender, SelectedItemChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        var item = e.SelectedItem as Zoo;
        if (item == null)
            return;
        item.ImageUrl = "https://3.bp.blogspot.com/-W__wiaHUjwI/Vt3Grd8df0I/AAAAAAAAA78/7xqUNj8ujtY/s1600/image02.png";
    }

    public ObservableCollection<Zoo> Zoos { get; set; }
}

public class Zoo : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    private string _ImageUrl;

    public string ImageUrl
    {
        get { return _ImageUrl; }
        set
        {
            if (value != _ImageUrl)
            {
                _ImageUrl = value;
                OnPropertyChanged("ImageUrl");
            }
        }
    }

    private string _Name;

    public string Name
    {
        get { return _Name; }
        set
        {
            if (value != _Name)
            {
                _Name = value;
                OnPropertyChanged("Name");
            }
        }
    }

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    protected void OnPropertyChanged(string propertyName)
    {
        var handler = PropertyChanged;
        if (handler != null)
            handler(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
    }
}
```

Once an item is selected, you can find this item's instance in `SelectedItemChangedEventArgs`, then you can change the image source of this item.

**Update:**

Based on our discussion, I think the item sources for your `CarouselView` for thumbnails and the `CarouselView` for your larger images are in the same sequential order, then when you select the item in your thumbnails, you can get the position of thumbnails and scroll the `CarouselView` for larger images like this:

```
var postion = CarouselThunbnails.Position;
CarouselImages.Position = postion;
```

Comment: Thanks for helping out. But the issue I'm facing is where I have a couple of thumbnails and all these thumbnails are also bound to the flipview. And when the user taps on the thumbnail I make the FlipView visible where the image is shown in a larger format. But I'm not able to set the item in the FlipView for the tapped item. Normally I can make the FlipView visible and swipe to move around and see other images. Its just that I can't open an item in between. If that makes sense.

Comment: @AbsoluteSith, sounds like you want to insert an item in the specific position when you select a thumbnail? You have two `CarouselView`, one is for thumbnails the other is for a larger format of images? My demo shows how to change the image when the item of `CarouselView` is selected.

Comment: But since I'm using an ItemSource binding I don't need to set the image when a CarouselView is selected. But these CarouselView is just showing me images in sequential order. Its just I want to select a particular position in that sequence.

Comment: @AbsoluteSith, so, you mean you want to make the `CarouselView` automatically be scrolled to specific item when you select an item in your thumbnails?

Comment: Correct. Just like any Photos app.

Comment: @AbsoluteSith, I've updated my answer, use the `Position` property, this property helps get/set the current shown item's position in the `CarouselView`.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/134941/discussion-between-absolutesith-and-grace-feng-msft).