# In Xamarin Forms how do I change the current item in my Carousel View from my ViewModel or code behind?

Tags: c#, xaml, xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.android

Like the title says I want to change the current item of my Carousel View through the source code. So the thing is I have a Page with a Carousel View and I Have a timer on there, I want to be able to change the current item to the next one when the timer reaches zero. Is there actually a way to do that. I used `Device.StartTimer` for the timer but I am not sure if it's the best solution here for what I want. Here is my xaml:

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
 <ContentPage
    x:Class="FitnessApp.Views.WourkoutPage"
    xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
    xmlns:helpers="clr-namespace:FitnessApp.Helpers"
    xmlns:viewmodel="clr-namespace:FitnessApp.ViewModels"
    Title="{Binding Title}"
    Shell.NavBarIsVisible="True">

<ContentPage.BindingContext>
    <viewmodel:WorkoutViewModel />
</ContentPage.BindingContext>

<Grid Padding="0,10" RowDefinitions="*, Auto">
    <Label FontSize="Large" Text="{Binding Countdown}" />
    <CarouselView
        Grid.Row="0"
        CurrentItemChangedCommand="{Binding CarouselItemChangedCommand}"
        CurrentItemChangedCommandParameter="{Binding Source={RelativeSource Self}, Path=CurrentItem}"
        IndicatorView="myIndicator"
        ItemsSource="{Binding ExercisesToDo}"
        Loop="False"
        PeekAreaInsets="10">
        <CarouselView.ItemsLayout>
            <LinearItemsLayout
                ItemSpacing="0"
                Orientation="Horizontal"
                SnapPointsType="MandatorySingle" />
        </CarouselView.ItemsLayout>
        <CarouselView.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <StackLayout>
                    <Frame
                        Margin="0"
                        BorderColor="DarkGray"
                        CornerRadius="5"
                        HasShadow="True"
                        HeightRequest="500"
                        HorizontalOptions="Center"
                        VerticalOptions="CenterAndExpand">
                        <Grid RowDefinitions="5*, *, .6*, .5*, *">
                            <BoxView
                                Grid.Row="0"
                                BackgroundColor="Bisque"
                                HeightRequest="150"
                                HorizontalOptions="Center"
                                WidthRequest="300" />
                            <Label
                                Grid.Row="1"
                                HorizontalOptions="Center"
                                Text="{Binding Exercise.Name}" />
                            <Rectangle
                                Grid.Row="2"
                                Grid.RowSpan="2"
                                BackgroundColor="Aqua" />
                            <Label
                                Grid.Row="2"
                                FontSize="Large"
                                HorizontalOptions="Center"
                                Text="{Binding Source={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type viewmodel:WorkoutViewModel}}, Path=Countdown}"
                                VerticalOptions="Center" />
                            <Label
                                Grid.Row="3"
                                FontSize="Small"
                                HorizontalOptions="Center"
                                Text="Seconds"
                                VerticalOptions="Center" />
                            <Button
                                Grid.Row="4"
                                BackgroundColor="Black"
                                FontFamily="FASolid"
                                FontSize="Large"
                                Text="{x:Static helpers:FAIcons.Play}"
                                TextColor="AliceBlue" />
                        </Grid>
                    </Frame>
                </StackLayout>
            </DataTemplate>
        </CarouselView.ItemTemplate>
    </CarouselView>
    <IndicatorView
        x:Name="myIndicator"
        Grid.Row="1"
        HorizontalOptions="Center"
        IndicatorColor="LightGray"
        SelectedIndicatorColor="DarkGray" />
</Grid>
</ContentPage>
```

and my viewmodel:

```
using FitnessApp.Models;
using MvvmHelpers;
using MvvmHelpers.Commands;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Xamarin.Forms;

namespace FitnessApp.ViewModels
{
    public class WorkoutViewModel : ViewModelBase
    {
        public static int countSeconds;
        public ObservableRangeCollection<ExerciseToDo> ExercisesToDo { get; set; }

        public MvvmHelpers.Commands.Command<ExerciseToDo> CarouselItemChangedCommand { get; }
        System.Timers.Timer countdownTimer;
        public WorkoutViewModel()
        {
            Title = "Magic";

            ExercisesToDo = new ObservableRangeCollection<ExerciseToDo>();

            CarouselItemChangedCommand = new MvvmHelpers.Commands.Command<ExerciseToDo>(CasrouselItemChanged);

            ExercisesToDo.Add(new ExerciseToDo { Exercise = new Exercise { Name = "90/90 Crunch" }, Countdown = 30 });
            ExercisesToDo.Add(new ExerciseToDo { Exercise = new Exercise { Name = "Leg Raise" }, Countdown = 35 });
            ExercisesToDo.Add(new ExerciseToDo { Exercise = new Exercise { Name = "Twisting Pistons" }, Countdown = 40 });
            ExercisesToDo.Add(new ExerciseToDo { Exercise = new Exercise { Name = "Starfish Crunch" }, Countdown = 60 });
            ExercisesToDo.Add(new ExerciseToDo { Exercise = new Exercise { Name = "Russian Twists" }, Countdown = 20 });

            Device.StartTimer(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1), () =>
            {
                countSeconds--;
                Countdown = $"{countSeconds}";

                return Convert.ToBoolean(countSeconds);
            });
        }

        void CasrouselItemChanged(ExerciseToDo exerciseToDo)
        {
            if (exerciseToDo == null)
                return;

            countSeconds = ExercisesToDo[ExercisesToDo.IndexOf(exerciseToDo)].Countdown;
        }

        public string countdown = countSeconds.ToString();
        public string Countdown
        {
            get => countdown;
            set => SetProperty(ref countdown, value);
        }

    }
}
```

I tried searching for this but couldn't really find anything. I currently haven't put anything in my code behind as I wanted to use the view model more, but I am open to any solution and if there is a way to do it from the code behind I would love to know. Thanks in advance.

Comment: if you read the [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/user-interface/carouselview/interaction) you can either set the `CurrentItem` or `Position` properties

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to set the item for a CarouselView from code behind?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42019469/how-to-set-the-item-for-a-carouselview-from-code-behind)